# How get list of images using kubernetes API?

Tags: kubernetes, google-container-registry, docker-image

I'm trying to read Images using the kubernetes API, but am not seeing an API for that.
Is there an API to Read Images List from my google cloud account?

Comment: I think you need to be a little more specific with your question. Do you know of a gcloud command that does something similar to what you are trying to do with the API? Or do you even really need to go through the API at all?

Answer (score 4):

To list all images in your gcr.io private registry, you can use the [docker search](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/search/) command, pointing at your registry, using your Google credentials:

```
gcloud docker search gcr.io/your-registry
```

Or in two steps, configuring `docker` to use your Google credentials:

```
gcloud docker -a
docker search gcr.io/your-registry
```